# Can I redeem my reputation with a faction?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Unfortunately, I'm vilified in the Legion, so I wasn't able to do any quests for them (except for the one given in Nipton (*Cold, Cold Heart*)). Sometimes when I look at reputation in my Pip-Boy some entries are gone and looking at the map I see Neutral standing with those factions, but as soon as I talk to an NPC the reputation is reverted to the original state (this may actually be a glitch in the game). Is there a way to finish Legion quests if they hate me? Furthermore - is it possible to finish side quests for both NCR and Ceasar's Legion if they hate each other so much?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Sometimes when I look at reputation in my Pip-Boy some entries are gone and looking at the map I see Neutral standing with those factions, but as soon as I talk to an NPC the reputation is reverted to the original state (this may actually be a glitch in the game).

If this is not a glitch, it may be because you are disguised as a member of a faction that is Neutral, but have been recognized when entering dialog.

If you haven't completed Ring-A-Ding-Ding yet, after completing it your negative reputation with the Legion and the NCR is going to be reset, so you can go to their quest trees. If you have become Vilified *after* completing Ring-A-Ding-Ding, there's no way for them to accept you again, and their quest line is going to fail.

> Furthermore - is it possible to finish side quests for both NCR and Caesar's Legion if they hate each other so much?

Only some quests can be completed in the main quest line for each side before the other turns against you. As for the side quests, be aware that some quests inflict negative reputation on some reputations when they are solved.

Comment: No, I have not completed the Ring-A-Ding-Ding quest yet (despite for playing for over 80 hours and being at 27lvl, I have not even entered The Strip yet! This game is *LONG*, seriously...). Do I have to do anything special on that quest or will the reputation reset automatically? I can go and play with Legion then?
My BoS Power Armor doesn't help (at least with NCR) :P, but I always carry some other armor just for when I want to talk to hostile NPCs.

Comment: Any completion of Ring-A-Ding-Ding will reset your reputation, and open the main lines of quests for each faction. I recommend, after completing it, to save and keep that save file for when you want to go back and change the faction you want to favor.

Comment: BTW. seems like the reputation reset is actually connected to my BoS armor - when I'm not wearing it, I'm vilified in the Legion and have the Wild Child (unfortunately, I don't know how that happened...) reputation with the NCR, but when I wear the Power Armor it changes to Neutral on the map and I can talk to the Legion - at least no one attacked me, which cannot be said about NCR of course. ;)

Comment: Yeah, just be careful that some guards in Legion camps may see through your disguise and alert other people.